# Mac NFS client needs to mount debian NFS server

Tags: linux, macos, debian, mount, nfs

Mac NFS client(192.168.0.14) and debian NFS server(192.168.0.3). On Mac, `showmount -e` has the debian network address listed. But if `mount -t nfs -o resvport 192.168.0.3:/home/nfs /debian`, an error shows up as `mount:realpath /automount/static/debian operation not permitted`. `/debian` is the local directory on Mac. `/home/nfs/` is the directory on debian to be mounted.

`uname -a` on Mac shows `Darwin xx.xx.xx 8.11.1 Darwin Kernel Version 8.11.1`. `uname -a` on debian shows `Linux debian.xx.xx 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64`.

I actually setup exports on both of them, hoping to see they can mount to each other. Now debian can mount to Mac, but Mac couldn't do it to debian. Super user doesn't work either.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suspect they're using incompatible versions of NFS.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for your reply. Yes I just checked the NFS are of different versions. The one on Mac is version 3 and the one on linux is version 4.

Comment: Check whether there's an option on the server to allow older version clients.